# How can I do a barrel

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-3dplot, ellipsis

Hello dear users of PGFplots,
I need to do this figure, a barrel.
How can I do this by using PGFplots?

[image]

Comment: You woulsn't do this in pgfplots but rather in TikZ

Answer (score 10):

The only slightly nontrivial task here is to compute the critical angle of the (curved) vertical boundary of the barrel. This answer attempts doing something potentially new. To the best of my knowledge, so far these values have been computed in a "basis-dependent" way, and the expression differs on whether one uses `pgfplots`, `tikz-3dplot` or, as in this answer, the `perspective` library to install the 3d view. Here this gets computed in an independent way, this is what the mysterious function `phicrit` does. All the rest is standard.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{irk}{RGB}{138,204,183}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{phicrit}{0}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\pgf@xx,\pgf@yx)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={110}{15},declare function={rr(\x)=2.3*exp(-\x*\x/45);
    h=3;},>=stealth,semithick]
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Z using {-2*h+\X*h}] in {1,2,3}
 {\draw[irk,inner color=irk!20!white,outer color=irk!80!white]
  plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,domain=0:360] 
  ({rr(\Z)*sin(\t)},{rr(\Z)*cos(\t)},\Z);
 \draw[magenta,ultra thick] (0,0,\Z) -- (0,{rr(\Z)},\Z);
 \ifcase\X
 \or
  \fill[magenta] (0,0,\Z) circle[radius=3pt];
  \path (0,0,\Z) node[left=1ex] {$-h$}  -- node[above] {$r$} (0,{rr(\Z)},\Z);
 \or
   \path (0,0,\Z) -- node[above] {$R$} (0,{rr(\Z)},\Z);
 \or
  \fill[magenta] (0,0,\Z) circle[radius=3pt];
  \path (0,0,\Z) node[left=1ex] {$h$} -- node[above] {$r$} (0,{rr(\Z)},\Z);
 \fi 
 \ifnum\X<3
  \draw[dashed,gray] (0,0,\Z) -- ++ (0,0,h);
 \else
  \draw[->] (0,0,\Z) -- ++ (0,0,1) node[pos=1.2] {$z$};
 \fi}
 \draw[irk] plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=-h:h] 
  ({rr(\t)*sin(phicrit)},{rr(\t)*cos(phicrit)},\t); 
 \draw[irk] plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=-h:h] 
  ({rr(\t)*sin(phicrit+180)},{rr(\t)*cos(phicrit+180)},\t); 
 \draw[dashed,gray] ({rr(0)},0,0) -- ({-rr(0)-1},0,0)
    (0,{rr(0)},0) -- (0,{-rr(0)-1},0);
 \draw[->] ({rr(0)},0,0) -- ++ (1,0,0) node[pos=1.2] {$x$};  
 \draw[->] (0,{rr(0)},0) -- ++ (0,1,0) node[pos=1.2] {$y$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some of these barrels get visited by marmots, who take care of the honey liquor.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{phicrit}{0}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\pgf@xx,\pgf@yx)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr(\x)=2.3*exp(-\x*\x/45);
    h=3;},>=stealth,semithick]
 \fill[3d view={110}{15}] plot[variable=\t,smooth cycle,domain=0:360,samples=37] 
  ({rr(h)*sin(\t)},{rr(h)*cos(\t)},h);  
 \marmot[3D,shift={(0,1.5)},scale=1.4,whiskers,teeth]
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \CF using {int(70+20*cos(\X*30+80))}] in {1,...,12}    
 {\draw[3d view={110}{15},top color=brown!\CF!black!80!white,bottom color=brown!\CF!black!80!white] 
  plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=-h:h] 
  ({rr(\t)*sin(phicrit+\X*15-15)},{rr(\t)*cos(phicrit+\X*15-15)},\t) -- 
  plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=0:15] 
  ({rr(h)*sin(phicrit+\X*15-15+\t)},{rr(h)*cos(phicrit+\X*15-15+\t)},h) --
  plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=h:-h] 
  ({rr(\t)*sin(phicrit+\X*15)},{rr(\t)*cos(phicrit+\X*15)},\t) --
  plot[variable=\t,smooth,domain=15:0] 
  ({rr(-h)*sin(phicrit+\X*15-15+\t)},{rr(-h)*cos(phicrit+\X*15-15+\t)},-h)
  -- cycle; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a cute marmot!

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Self-quarantine. :-(